# How to install Ubuntu if the free space appears as unusable?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7. I made a partition while preparing for the installation in windows of 50Gb. I'm trying to install it right now and after making selecting some space for the swap (i dont know what that is. I'm an absolute beginner and the guide says so) I should now make some other partitions for Ubuntu, but i cant use the remaining space. I'm afraid of deleting anything because the other partitions are from windows.

Right now I can't event access Windows. I'm afraid it might have somehow disappeared.

[image: This is what the screen looks like]

To be honest what I'm most concerned right now is recovering Windows, but I guess that it is impossible to do so until Ubuntu has finished installing.

Comment: Your disk looks like it's formatted using MBR which allows only 4 partitions thus the spare space is *unusable* as it states. You didn't say what release of Ubuntu, and later release do not need swap space (they can use swapfiles) but this depends on what release you are installing (*which you didn't say*).  If you are using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS or later, I'd remove the swap, and use that (letting the system use swapfile for swap).

Comment: Can you select the "unusable" space, press "Change..." and then "Use as EXT4"? If not, your disk has a maximum of 4 partitions, as @guiverc explains.

Comment: @thAngryUnicorn guiverc nailed it. since this is an old laptop it shipped with windows 7 and the partitioning sheme which was popular (and the only choice?) at the time : MBR. but GPT is where it's at. I would personally reinstall windows 7 after changing the drive to GPT but I can feel that that wouldn't be what you want. the easiest solution here is to add a hard drive (if there's room for it) make sure the ubuntu usb installer you create is set to MBR not GPT (rufus usb key maker allows you to pick this setting) then install ubuntu to the new drive and it will automagically be a dual boot.

Comment: @thAngryUnicorn oh you put swap! why put SWAP???? delete swap. problem solved.

Comment: One if the partitions, sda2 or sda3 is your Windows partition. It doesn't look like it's deleted although you may have messed up its boot files which look like they are in sda1 but should have been formatted in FAT32. Quit the installation of Ubuntu. What message are you getting when you try to boot up? Did you make a Windows 7 recovery disk beforehand?